# Azure logic apps batch restart failed runs

Tags: azure-logic-apps

We have run into a situation where due to our SQL server being down a whole lot of azure logic app runs have failed.

What is the best way to bulk restart them, without doing it manually one by one in the UI? Is it possible to do that using CLI / REST APIs?

Answer (score 3):

For now you could bulk resubmit Logic Apps from the Runs Dashboard. Select the runs that you want to resubmit and click on the Resubmit button at the top right.

[image]
[image]

Comment: For those having trouble finding this dashboard, it can be accessed from the associated Log Analytics workspace --> Workspace Summary --> Logic Apps Management (Runs) --> Logic App runs.

From here, Logic Apps can be filtered and marked in bulk for resubmission.

Documentation is found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/monitor-logic-apps-log-analytics#view-logic-app-runs-status